# Oracle DB import error

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, import

I get the error below when importing a database - any ideas why?  I do this type of import all the time and I've never seen this error.

Prior to doing the import we drop all objects in the schema.  The import always fails when importing the same table..

```
  [exec] IMP-00017: following statement failed with ORACLE error 1:
     [exec] "BEGIN   DBMS_JOB.ISUBMIT(JOB=>99,WHAT=>' quemon();',NEXT_DATE=>TO_DATE('400"
     [exec] "0-01-01:00:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD:HH24:MI:SS'),INTERVAL=>'SYSDATE + 1/144 /* 1 "
     [exec] "Hour */',NO_PARSE=>TRUE); END;"
     [exec] IMP-00003: ORACLE error 1 encountered
     [exec] ORA-00001: unique constraint (SYS.I_JOB_JOB) violated
     [exec] ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_JOB", line 97
```

Answer (score 2):

You already have a job in the target database that is numbered 99. You'll need to drop that job.

Edit: The ISUBMIT procedure of dbms_job is a bit hard to find docs on. [Here](http://www.psoug.org/reference/dbms_job.html) is where I found some. That procedure submits a job with a specified job number, whereas the SUBMIT procedure assigns a job number for you, avoiding this very problem. To remove the offending job (in your case), run:

```
execute dbms_job.remove(99);
```

Comment: Trying that ...

Comment: Be careful if you choose to remove a job using `DMBS_JOB.REMOVE()`, since you don't know exactly what job you remove, in which schema. Simply use first DCookie's suggestion: use `DBMS_JOB.SUBMIT()` instead of `DBMS_JOB.ISUBMIT()` which will always create a new job, so no risk :) See also http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20302/materialized-view-does-not-import-properly-when-importing-a-db-for-a-second-time/36908#36908